# How to change the IP address of Amazon EC2 instance using boto library

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

How can I assign a new IP address (or Elastic IP) to an already existing AWS EC2 instance using boto library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have set properly with `~/.boto` and connect to aws, have the boto module ready in python. If not, go through this first: [Getting Started with Boto](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html)

For example, you need assign a new EIP `54.12.23.34` to the instance `i-12345678`

Make sure, EIP has been allocated(existed) and you can get its `allocation_id`.

```
$ python
>>> import boto.ec2
>>> conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-west-2")
>>> conn.get_all_addresses()
>>> allocation=conn.get_all_addresses(filters={'public_ip': '54.12.23.34'})[0].allocation_id
u'eipalloc-b43b3qds'
```

then call [associate_address](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.associate_address) and give `instance_id` or `private_ip_address`, then you should be fine to assign the EIP to Amazon EC2 instance using boto library

#### associate_address usage:

> associate_address(instance_id=None, public_ip=None, allocation_id=None, network_interface_id=None, private_ip_address=None, allow_reassociation=False, dry_run=False)

So you will have the command as:

```
>>> conn.associate_address(instance_id='i-12345678', allocation_id=allocation)
```